# Which Exception should I get when RabbitMQ as a broker for Celery is out of memory?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I have an application which uses Celery with RabbitMQ as a broker.

Recently I've noticed that the application became slow. All RabbitMQ Connections had the state "blocking" and the used memory was pretty much at the high watermark.

After making sure that RabbitMQ has enough memory, a couple of connections went to the "running" state and the overall system normalized.

Now I want to be able to recognize this earlier. While I will improve the monitoring/alerting for RabbitMQ itself, I was wondering if it's possible to detect this state on the Celery app side. What does Celery do when all connections of the broker are blocking / when the broker has issues?